# Does changing MYSQL table engine from MYISAM to INNODB can cause a data corruptions?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have a simple question.
I have a mysql databases. I have 2 tables, that uses MYISAM, I want to change to INNODB, one of the table has 1.000 rows, if I do this this change, is there a risk that it will cause any corruption of my data/rows?

Comment: I don't know of any "corruption", but here are some things to watch for:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: 'one of the table has +/- 1.000 rows' - what do you mean by this? - after conversion table has gained 1000 rows? after conversion table has lost 1000 rows? how did you find out?

Comment: No, I meant the original table with MyISAM has at least 1000 rows (give or take). I edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: @Galbert You might want to look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html

Answer (score -2):

The two main advantages to switch to InnoDB are reliability and scalability.
Also InnoDB is more granular due to row level locks while MyISAM supports table level locks. Crash recovery in InnoDB is a way better. But bear in mind that **it can cause some headaches**

I would strongly suggest to check official docs [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220504012549/https://mariadb.com/kb/en/converting-tables-from-myisam-to-innodb/) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211125165403/http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb)

Comment: This avoids answering the (unclear) question by deflection and copies a previous comment you can expect downvotes (though not from me)

Comment: SAlame this question was wide open... thats all folks